# Video chat between different applications with opentok

Tags: java, audio, video, chat

I'm building a web application that will run locally on each of the users' pc (local web server using Jetty application server). I want the users to be able to talk to each other (on to one, not group) using video and audio. The users can exchange messages between each other in a p2p way, but they don't have a central server that will host one application. Is this possible? Can users talk using opentok, from different applications? Is there another solution other than opentok? I'm looking for something free and open source.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Opentok platform supports both P2P mode and using their servers... So you can use OpenTok for your application.  I wouldn't recommend it... you won't have this back up.

Peer-to-peer streaming uses UDP. A firewall may block UDP and cause peer-to-peer streaming to fail. If peer-to-peer streaming fails, either when streams are initially published or during the course of a session, the session falls back to using the OpenTok servers for relaying streams.

[P2P with Opentok](http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api/tools/js/documentation/overview/peer_to_peer.html)